# Suppress automake's canonicalization warning of a variable name

Tags: automake

In my automake project I have an exported variable calles `SIMULATION_LDFLAGS` which is used to build my project for use in a system simulator.

Unfortunately the automake convention to append `_LDFLAGS, _SOURCES`, etc. to the canonicalized program name causes a warning when creating the Makefile.in files, because the `SIMULATION_LDFLAGS` variable "refers" to a program SIMULATION which does, of course, not exist.

The actual output of automake is

> src/Makefile.am:15: variable `SIMULATION_LDFLAGS' is defined but no program or
>   src/Makefile.am:15: library has`SIMULATION' as canonical name (possible typo)

Is there a way to tell automake that this variable is not part of its usual variable-name-matching magic?

Comment: I think `-Wno-syntax` in AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE will do it, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to tell automake that this variable is not part of its usual variable-name-matching magic?

I don't think that there is a way to give automake a list of exceptions like this.